# Determine which sections of UITableViewController are visible when it is scrolled

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift2

I am trying to determine which section of the UITableView is visible (on top, if there are 2 sections simultaneously), in swift 2. So far I found this solution:
[Is there any way to know if the user is scrolling tableview up or down? in swift IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32313773/is-there-any-way-to-know-if-the-user-is-scrolling-tableview-up-or-down-in-swift) , this: [How to get a UITableView's visible sections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191317/how-to-get-a-uitableviews-visible-sections) and this one:  [Swift - UITableView scroll event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189530/swift-uitableview-scroll-event)

All of them not working for me for reasons:

**1.** I can not add UIScrollViewDelegate, because swift 2 is giving error on redundant conforming to protocol (because it is UITalbeView, and it already conforms to UIScrollView).

**2.** However, this:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll () {
    print("scrolled: \(self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows)")
}
```

is never being launched.

Delegate and data source for the UITableView are defined through storyboard interface builder.

How would you determine in **swift 2** that UITableViewController is being scrolled, and which section is visible?

Comment: are u useing willDisplayCell  method?

Comment: please try to get visible cell from this method and then get section from this visible cell.

Comment: @VvkAghera , it works! thank you, can you post this as an answer please, maybe someone will need it later.

Comment: i am not working on Swift i know only objectiveC. so   :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please try to get visible cell from **willDisplayCell** method and then get section from this visible cell. 
For Example:
First get Indexpath from Cell and then retrive section from Indexpath.

**let section = indexPath.section**

Code is:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell") as! CustomCellViewController

    let position: CGPoint = cell.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(position)
    {
        let section = indexPath.section
        print("will display section: \(section)")
    }
}
```

Comment: great answer thx. 1 thing tho, you should not dequeue cells in this method. Just use the cell property in the delegate.

Comment: @crashoverride777 dequeue is used in cellForRow at indexpath method.

Comment: hey, yes, and the above code is willDisplayCell, were we should not dequeue.